# Read an XML file generated by WFS

Tags: openlayers, wfs, xml

I want to read variables from an XML file generated by a WFS. I do this with WMS but I didn't find the equivalent of it in case of using WFS. Do you have any idea ?

here is my code :

```
ol.control.LayerControl.prototype.showNewLayerPanel = function(btn){
var this_ = this; //get it ready to be passed on listener functions
var urlsArray = this.options.capabilitiesURLs;
var capabJsonDocs = new Array();
  for (var i=0;i<urlsArray.length;i++){
      Ext.Ajax.request({
          url     : urlsArray[i],
          method  : 'GET', 
          async   : false, 
          success: function(response) {
              var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
              capabJsonDocs.push(parser.read(response.responseXML));
              console.log("capabJsonDocs",capabJsonDocs)
          }
      });
  }
```

I have  `options.capabilitiesURLs : ['{my_path}/geoserver/PFE/wms?request=GetCapabilities']`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't find it in the openlayers. I had to read the xml document to get the layers. Adding that to your existing logic would be something like below:

```
   ol.control.LayerControl.prototype.showNewLayerPanel = function(btn){
        var this_ = this; //get it ready to be passed on listener functions
        var urlsArray = this.options.capabilitiesURLs;
        var capabXMLDocs = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<urlsArray.length;i++){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url     : urlsArray[i],
                method  : 'GET', 
                async   : false, 
                success: function(response) {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                    capabXMLDocs.push(xmlDoc);
                    console.log("capabXMLDocs",capabXMLDocs);
                }
            });
        }
   }

 You can read the variable xmlDoc like below: 
 var capabilities = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("wfs:WFS_Capabilities")[0];
 var layers_parent = capabilities.getElementsByTagName("FeatureTypeList")[0];
 var layers = layers_parent.getElementsByTagName("FeatureType");
```